# How many values can IMAP MIME BODYSTRUCTURE format string be nested?

Tags: php, imap, mime, mime-mail

Is there any way a MIME format string would be nested more than 3 decimal points when retrieving individual parts from an IMAP server? For example, RFC3501 section 6.4.5, pg56, when describing how to parse rfc822 messages from the server, if I want to get the plaintext version of an email from the IMAP server, it's possible (and common when dealing w/rfc822 messages w/attachments) to issue

```
tag FETCH uid BODY[4.2.2.1]
```

as rfc822 messages can be nested deeply. So there are 3 decimal points in that format string. My question is, is there any reason, any type of MIME message could look like this?

```
tag FETCH uid BODY[1.2.3.4.5]
```

Or is 3 decimal points the maximum amount of nesting possible? I've yet to find so on my tests but before I implement this in my parser I need to know for sure as RFC3501 is not specific about this. If more than 3 decimal points in a MIME format string are possible, what would the BODYSTRUCTURE of said message look like?

Thank you for your time, I look forward to your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer, while there are no limits in rfc204x nor rfc3501, every mail server I have tried imposes it's own limits as exaggerated MIME nesting seems to be a common way to get around various filters like spam, .exe blocking, etc. "MIME nesting exceeds safety limit" appears to be the popular message to return when sending 15+ levels of decimals.

Comment: Unless you intend to test every possible mail server, the only way to be robust is to support an arbitrary depth. If you're doing this in-house and know that your mail server has a specific limit, then it's a valid approach but if your code is going to be in the wild, this limitation will bite someone at some time

Answer (score 0):

Rfc3501 (which you linked) states

```
BODY[<section>]<<partial>>

    The text of a particular body section.  The section
    specification is a set of zero or more part specifiers
    delimited by periods...
```

That seems to state pretty explicitly that there is no upper bound.

As to what such a message would be used for, I don't know

Comment: For me, "zero or more part specifiers" doesn't explicitly state "no upper bounds". Thanks for your input, but I'd appreciate it if you made your answer a bit more clear/specific by detailing what a BODYSTRUCTURE w/4 or more periods would look like. My testers and I have parsed huge amounts of emails and yet to find an instance of this. Outside of rfc822 messages, I've yet to see more than 2 periods in the section argument. Right now, I'm thinking that in theory, it could be possible but in practice it isn't going to happen.

Comment: I'm not aware of any formal definition in regards to RFCs - so you may be right - but it's worth noting that both the XML spec and regular expressions use the phrase to many any `n >= 0`.

Comment: What do you mean XML & regex? My question has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Apologies if I was unclear. I disagree with your reading of the spec, so I was giving a couple of prominent examples where the term "zero or more", it's taken to mean `n >= 0` and explicitly does not include an upper bound. One example was [regular expressions](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html#uh-7). That's not to say anyone ever bothers implementing it that way - or that it's ever used - just the spec says it's possible.

Comment: No need to apologize, I technically understand what >=, XML & RegEx are. For you to prove that "there is no upper bound", you'd have to show me a BODYSTRUCTURE proving that, until then I have to code my client under the assumption that MIME messages can only be nested so far, which is 3 decimal points. While the RFC doesn't state an upper bound, the upper bound would be MIME's limits.

Answer (score 0):

There is no upper limit. The longest I've seen is this little baby, where the Content-Description messages have been edited to contain the part numbers:

```
* 1 FETCH (BODYSTRUCTURE (("text" "plain" NIL NIL "Part number 1" "7BIT" 9 1 NIL NIL NIL NIL)("application" "octet-stream" NIL NIL "Part number 2" "BASE64" 14 "qWXKy9s0ny8E1/5/uzNhpg==" ("attachment" ("filename" "foo.bar" "size" "8")) NIL NIL)("message" "rfc822" NIL NIL "Part number 3" "7BIT" 540 ("Thu, 20 May 2004 14:28:50 +0200" "embedded rfc822 message" (("B" NIL "b" "c.d")) NIL NIL (("A" NIL "a" "c.d")) NIL NIL NIL NIL) (("text" "plain" NIL NIL "Part number 3.1" "7BIT" 9 1 NIL ("inline" NIL) ("en" "no" "de") NIL)("application" "octet-stream" NIL NIL "Part number 3.2" "BASE64" 14 NIL NIL NIL NIL) "mixed" ("boundary" "Y") NIL NIL NIL) 24 NIL NIL NIL NIL)(("image" "gif" NIL NIL "Part number 4.1" "BASE64" 0 NIL NIL NIL NIL)("message" "rfc822" NIL NIL "Part number 4.2" "7BIT" 658 ("Thu, 20 May 2004 14:28:50 +0200" "second embedded rfc822 message" (("A" NIL "a" "c.d")) NIL NIL (("B" NIL "b" "c.d")) NIL NIL NIL NIL) (("text" "plain" NIL NIL "Part number 4.2.1" "7BIT" 9 1 NIL NIL NIL NIL)(("text" "plain" NIL NIL "Part number 4.2.2.1" "7BIT" 9 1 NIL NIL "en" NIL)("text" "richtext" NIL NIL "Part number 4.2.2.2" "7BIT" 9 1 NIL NIL NIL NIL) "alternative" ("boundary" "B") NIL NIL NIL) "mixed" ("boundary" "A") NIL NIL NIL) 34 NIL NIL NIL NIL) "mixed" ("boundary" "Z") NIL NIL NIL) "mixed" ("boundary" "X") NIL NIL NIL))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer arnt, I was wondering when you'd chime in. In theory there is no upper limit, but it looks like as of this moment, it is not possible for a MIME message to go deeper than 3 decimal points?

Comment: It is certainly possible.  I can create an arbitrarily complex MIME message that is as deep as you want.  You can put an upper limit in your code, but 3 is awful low.  "I've only seen 3 in practise, so I'll use 3" is not a good design paradigm.  "I've only seen 3 in practise, so I'll use 16" would be way more resilient.  Why would you impose such a low limit?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to figure out how exactly to parse these messages. So far my parser can only go to 1.2.3, but yes now that you mention that, even though an actual MIME message representing data (as in a real one, representing a real email structure, not an arbitrarily complex with just a bunch of opening parenthesis that represents no real data) is probably limited to 3 deicmals - I'll make it capable of more.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about something, notice on the 5th bodystructure, part 3.2. There are 2 extended BODYSTRUCTURE values, the first is "mixed" and the next one is the atom value of 24. What does the 24 mean?

Comment: I thought the message that caused the BODYSTRUCTURE had more than 3? (BTW, I read SO via a feed, so when I chime in depends on the vagaries of my feed reader and my feed reading.)

Comment: I can't verify since I don't have access to the imap server that formatted that BODYSTRUCTURE, but going off of what you pasted int he Content-Description, the deepest message is "4.2.2.2" (richtext), which is only 3 decimals. I also just parsed an email with 6 RFC822 messages embedded, and it only got 2 decimals deep (deepest message was 1.2.3). So I think it depends a lot on the server. I also think I should have worded this question as "how many MIME messages can be nested inside itself"

Comment: (Years later.) I assumed that "decimals" referred to "decimal numbers", not "decimal points". I see. No, it doesn't depend on the server, it depends on the incoming message. A message that contains six text/rfc822 messages may have only two levels, but a message that  contains a text/rfc822 that contains a text/rfc822 that contains a text/rfc822 that contains a text/rfc822 that contains a text/rfc822 that contains a text/rfc822 that contains a text/rfc822  has *many* levels. The ultimate limit is far beyond the limits on message size.